# Why now log is working without console in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Previously code like this was leading to an error.
And the fix was to bind console to log.
But now it is working as expected.

```
//Past
var log = console.log;
log("Bingo");  // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

//Present
let log = console.log
log("A") /// A
```

So what is changed in chrome?

Comment: The `log` function is now bound to the `console` object by default. Same with the other stuff like `error`. It's been that way for a year or two now, at least. It's done to aid with development, so you can do, say, `arr.forEach(console.log)` without adding extra code

Comment: @vlaz Very interesting. Thank you for respond. This is THE answer. Do you know is this standard behaviour of all browsers?  Is there the specification for this behaviour?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I know FF followed suit some time after Chrome and I have no idea what Edge does right now. I also don't know if standards have anything to say about it but overall, I'd expect newer browsers to support that. But I wouldn't put `array.forEach(console.log)` in production code, in case somebody is using IE or something. I'd only recommend it for debugging/prototying or something.